# Migrating from Jackson to JSON-B

Tags: java, jackson, payara, jsonb-api

As we're moving from **Payara 4** to **Payara 5**, which using **JSON-B** (implemented by **Yasson**) as default, we're trying to configure JSON-B to have the same behavior as **Jackson**, which we used in Payara 4.

With Jackson we used the below configuration:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
```

How can I achieve the same behavior with JSON-B?

Answer (score 0):

check YassonProperties class. You should find it

Comment: If you need to acknowledge something, please comment.